# SharePoint 2010 - Trying to reconnect to a Different /Old Farm but forgot the Farm Passphrase

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, farm-setup

I am trying to recover a farm and reconnect to old the Old Farm, ie., the Original Configuration Database.  I unfortunately forgot the Farm Passphrase when it asks for it.  Is there anyway possible at all to recover this or some other solution to this issue?

I have tried the well known Powershell Commands below:

```
$passphrasereset = ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$Set-SPPassPhrase -PassPhrase $passphrasereset -Confirm
```

This only works on the current new Configuration database which doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not currently connected to the farm (a.k.a. config database) the passphrase cannot be recovered or changed.  It can only be done so by server currently joined to the farm.

You will have to recreate your farm configuration.  You can, however, setup your web applications and service applications from the databases you do have backed up.